# How to distinquish wordpress served links from non-wordpress served links

Tags: plugins

I am working on a legacy code where part of the website uses WP and other part ASP.net etc. Is there an easy way to tell me what content is coming from WP vs Non-WordPress? Since the codebase is large this can help me understand the flow of information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends very much on you setup and how you want to be able to see this.

If you look in the source code of a page, you are very likely to be able to see which page is WP generated, because there will be strings like `wp-content` and `wp-includes` present (for instance because `jquery` is loaded by default). You could also add a specific code to the head of your site like this:

```
add_action ('wp_head','wpse376765_add_code');
function wpse376765_add_code () {
  echo '<meta name="wpmademe">';
  }
```

If you want it to be visible in the page itself, the easiest way would be to attach a little marker for admins only by including this in the `functions.php` of your theme:

```
add_action ('wp_footer','wpse376765_add_code_to_footer');
function wpse376765_add_code_to_footer () {
  if (is_admin()) echo '<span>WP made me</span>';
  }
```

Comment: I am new to WP , but is it even feasible that just the menu is served by WP and rest by ASP.net? OR the entire page have to be a WP served page?

Comment: WP is very flexible, so, yes, that is possible. You would just have to write a function that calls an API at some point during page generation. This is for instance how you would include a Twitter feed in a WP page.

Comment: My former comment assumes that WP is called first and other concent delivery systems are called from it. That's not necessarily true. It could also be the other way around. Or even the server deciding which CMS to call based on the url.

Comment: Thansk a lot for your response. My query is little differenet. How can i find out if the Navigation bar in my website (legacy code) generated through WP. Will inpect element in browser help? Any specific tags to look for?

Comment: One more Naive question. Are these WP specific artifacts (nav-bar) embedded using javascipt code (.js files) or actual backend (ASP.net) server will call WP functions?

Comment: The navigation bar code is entirely generated by the theme developer, so there are not necessarily markers in the html that will betray WP. But if you go to the menu page in WP´s backend and change a little something there, you could see if it is reflected in the frontend.

Comment: there's a standard meta tag to specify the `generator` https://www.metatags.org/all-meta-tags-overview/meta-name-generator/, WP already adds such a tag unless a plugin/theme removes it

Answer (score 1):

WordPress outputs a generator meta tag using the `the_generator()` function, that you can use to identify it.

For example, WordPress.com sites have this:

```html
<meta name="generator" content="WordPress.com" />
```

https://www.metatags.org/all-meta-tags-overview/meta-name-generator/

Note that some themes/plugins remove this tag as it has no practical use for most developers and no SEO benefit

Comment: Or something like `<meta name="generator" content="WordPress 5.5.1" />` if the install is self hosted.