# How to figure out redirection and contents in hybrid solution containing word press content and legacy code (ASP.net)

Tags: wp-query, url-rewriting, mvc

I have legacy solution(ASP.net) hybrid with wordpress content, I have access to my ASP.net code base but not wordpress content. How can I figure out which section in my site is served through wordpress. E.g I suppose my navigation bar is served through wordpress and redirection to my Asp.net pages happens through it.
Considering the fact that I don't have access to wordpress admin site,

1. How can I make out which section is served through wordpress. Like if my nav-bar is from wrodpress or not because I don't see any signs of nav-bar being created or served through my Asp.net solution.
2. How can I understand the flow of redirection.
3. How all these things are integrated and served all-together.

Any dev-tools or plugins which can help?

I am all new to this kind of hybrid solution.

I can see a similar question asked in the link below but this is slightly more specific to my requirement:
[How to distinquish wordpress served links from non-wordpress served links](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/376765/how-to-distinquish-wordpress-served-links-from-non-wordpress-served-links/376768#376768?s=753101ac503344d185e02d8877f59f50)